# Debug .Net Core 3.1 Source Code in Visual Studio Mac 2019

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-mac, pdb-files

Note - this is for **Mac**. (Visual Studio 2019)

I am attempting to step into Asp .Net Web App code while debugging my web application but the functions are called without stepping into them. The project is using Microsoft.NetCore.App 3.1.0 and Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.8.

I have enabled `"Step into external code"` in the IDE preferences. Not sure what else I need to do.

Note, on application start up the application logs print warnings such as: Loaded `/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/3.1.8/System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.`

I can find no instructions on finding/installing the pdb files for .net core for mac for visual studio, nor am I sure whether I need to run the symbols server and how.

Not sure what else you'll need from me to work this issue out but I can provide.

Comment: This might help:
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-debug-asp-net-core-source-code-448544c16473?sk=58f24ef1f6b39d0bd2927cd36dbd690c